# Android make phone call by clicking a button not working for Galaxy 5

Tags: java, android, android-intent

In my `Android` application I have to make phone call to a particular number by clicking a button. I had written the following for that, it is working fine in my phone.

The same code is not working for client's mobile, he is having `Galaxy 5`, is there any reason for this

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    String number = "123456789";
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Permissions given in `manifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Can anyone help me.

Comment: Is it emergency number?

Comment: No its normal phone number

Comment: Do you get an exception ?

Comment: No exception coming, simply it did not worked in Galaxy 5 (it is NOT making the phone call)... same is working in my perfectly in my phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this method is inside you MainActivity` you must call it like:

```
    this.startActivity(intent);

//  ^ refers to MainActivity instance
```

If there is another class for the `Listener` think you must be able to see your `MainActivity` because is supposed to start the intent...

To avoid this you can do a couple of workarounds:

Make your `MainActivity` visible in `Listener` (create a custom attribute inside listener and fill it using a custom `Listener` constructor that accepts an activity).

Try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks I am checking it now